# Make script that fills and format cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Have to do some Apps Script for uni I cant do it, I have attached an image of what we have to make via the code

[image]

```
function myFunction() {

  var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

mysheet.getRange('a1').setValue('I Hate Programming')
mysheet.getRange('a2').setValue('I Hate Programming')
mysheet.getRange('a3').setValue('I Hate Programming')
mysheet.getRange('a4').setValue('It Works')
mysheet.getRange('a5').setValue('I Love Programming')
mysheet.getRange('a1:a5').setFontColor('#ff000')
mysheet.getRange('a1:a5').setBackgroundRGB(0,0,0)

mysheet.autoResizeColumn(1)
mysheet.setFrozenRows(5)
}
```

that is my current code, how ever I just get a black box with no text,

Comment: Please check out [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

mysheet.getRange('a1:a5').setFontColor('#ff0000')